# Need whole image to be clustered instead of face with DLIB

Tags: deep-learning, cluster-analysis, dlib

This is my code and current only the face of the image is saved in the target path i need the whole image to be clustered and saved in the target path . Let me know how can i modify this code

```
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Please specify valid arguments. Call the program like this \npython face_clustering.py -specify input folder- -specify output path-")
    exit()
# Download the pre trained models, unzip them and save them in the save folder as this file
predictor_path = 'shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat' # Download from http://dlib.net/files/dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat.bz2
face_rec_model_path = 'dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat' # Download from http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_5_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
faces_folder_path = sys.argv[1]
output_folder = sys.argv[2]

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() #a detector to find the faces
sp = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path) #shape predictor to find face landmarks
facerec = dlib.face_recognition_model_v1(face_rec_model_path) #face recognition model

descriptors = []
images = []
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.jpg")):
    print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
    print(f)
    img = dlib.load_rgb_image(f)
indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
    dets = detector(img, 1)
    print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))

    for k, d in enumerate(dets):
        # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
        shape = sp(img, d)
         face_descriptor = facerec.compute_face_descriptor(img, shape)
        descriptors.append(face_descriptor)
        images.append((img, shape))
labels = dlib.chinese_whispers_clustering(descriptors, 0.5)
num_classes = len(set(labels)) # Total number of clusters
for i in range(0, num_classes):
    indices = []
    class_length = len([label for label in labels if label == i])
    for j, label in enumerate(labels):
        if label == i:
            indices.append(j)
    print("Indices of images in the cluster {0} : {1}".format(str(i),str(indices)))
    print("Size of cluster {0} : {1}".format(str(i),str(class_length)))
    output_folder_path = output_folder + '/output' + str(i) # Output folder for each cluster
    os.path.normpath(output_folder_path)
    os.makedirs(output_folder_path)
    
    # Save each face to the respective cluster folder
    print("Saving faces to output folder...")
    for k, index in enumerate(indices):
        img, shape = images[index]
        file_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path,"face_"+str(k)+"_"+str(i))
        dlib.save_face_chip(img, shape, file_path, size=150, padding=0.25)
```

This is my code and current only the face of the image is saved in the target path i need the whole image to be clustered and saved in the target path . Let me know how can i modify this code